How can I ensure my UUID is saved to the DB after a new user registers with Strapi Auth?
I am facing an issue with my Strapi backend. When a new user registers using my Strapi auth system, I want to auto-generate a UUID using the strapi-advanced-uuid plugin to provide each user with a randomized unique identifier upon registration. However, this UUID isn't being saved to the database along with the rest of the new user's registration details.

Stack :

Next.js 14 (App Router)
Strapi v4.25.3 (node v20.11.1)

Schema for UUID :
// src/extensions/users-permissions/content-types/user/schema.json :

"uuid": {
  "type": "customField",
  "customField": "plugin::strapi-advanced-uuid.uuid"
}


The Issue :
The UUID is being successfully generated by my plugin, I can verify this by checking the newly registered user in my Content Manager Panel in Strapi Admin.
However, when I call the users endpoint I get an null response for my UUID despite it being present :
My endpoint :
http://localhost:1337/api/users?populate=*
My response :
 {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "testuser",
        "email": "testuser@example.com",
        "provider": "local",
        "createdAt": "2024-04-21T07:52:01.224Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-07-21T10:25:46.499Z",
        "uuid": null, // Returns as null
    }

Identified Issue :
I have however noticed that when I manually 'Save' the new user in the Content Manager the UUID appears in the API call :
  {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "testuser",
        "email": "testuser@example.com",
        "provider": "local",
        "createdAt": "2024-04-21T07:52:01.224Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-07-21T10:25:46.499Z",
        "uuid": "469875a9-b930-4421-a956-e8b49477ccd9",
    },

This leads me to think that the UUID is not being saved after creation to the DB.

What I've Tried :
I attempted to create a lifecycles.js hook in 'user-permissions' to no avail :
// src/extensions/users-permissions/content-types/user/lifecycles.js :

module.exports = {
  async afterCreate(event) {
    const { result } = event;
    console.log(
      "After Create - Initial result:",
      JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
    );

    if (result.uuid && typeof result.uuid === "object" && result.uuid.value) {
      console.log("UUID generated but not saved. Attempting to save...");
      try {
        const updatedUser = await strapi.entityService.update(
          "plugin::users-permissions.user",
          result.id,
          {
            data: { uuid: result.uuid.value },
          }
        );
        console.log(
          "User updated with UUID:",
          JSON.stringify(updatedUser, null, 2)
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error saving UUID:", error);
      }
    } else if (!result.uuid) {
      console.log(
        "No UUID found after creation. This should not happen if the plugin is working correctly."
      );
    } else {
      console.log("UUID appears to be already saved:", result.uuid);
    }
  },
};



So my question is, after a new users registers, and the UUID is generated, how do I save this auto-generated UUID field in my DB ?
